# negar expresion regular en r

Tags: r

me encuentro con el siguiente problema.
De la siguiente columna, quiero obtener solo los dígitos o composición de ellos, esto es, números o numero-numero: ejemplo 3,4,6 o 20-30

```
transprods <- data.frame(producto = c("tipo1 marca1 azul 22-33",
                                  "tipo2 marca2 az 10/20",
                                  "tipo3 marca2 rojo 30",
                                  "tipo4 marca21 amarillo am 20",
                                  "tipo1 marca3 am 20/10 cac",
                                  "tipo3 marca2 lila 15/25",
                                  "tipo2 marca2 30 3 azul",
                                  "tipo1 marca3 30/20 amarillo")) %>% as.tibble
```

cuya salida es:

```
  producto                   
 <fct>                       
tipo1 marca1 azul 22-33     
tipo2 marca2 az 10/20       
tipo3 marca2 rojo 30        
tipo4 marca21 amarillo am 20
tipo1 marca3 am 20/10 cac   
tipo3 marca2 lila 15/25     
tipo2 marca2 30 3 azul      
tipo1 marca3 30/20 amarillo
```

lo que primero hago es normalizar los numero con "/" para que sean separados por un "-"

luego, aplico la expresion regular

```
productos %>%
mutate(producto = gsub('[/]','-',producto),
     X2 = gsub('([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})','',producto))

A tibble: 8 x 2
producto                     X2                        
<chr>                        <chr>                     
tipo1 marca1 azul 22-33      "tipo1 marca1 azul "      
tipo2 marca2 az 10-20        "tipo2 marca2 az "        
tipo3 marca2 rojo 30         "tipo3 marca2 rojo "      
tipo4 marca21 amarillo am 20 "tipo4 marca amarillo am "
tipo1 marca3 am 20-10 cac     tipo1 marca3 am  cac      
tipo3 marca2 lila 15-25       "tipo3 marca2 lila "      
tipo2 marca2 30 3 azul        tipo2 marca2  3 azul      
tipo1 marca3 30-20 amarillo   tipo1 marca3  amarillo
```

que elimina todos los números y numeros separados con "-" pero cuando quiero negar la expresión mediante el patrón `'^([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})'` para quedarme solamente números y numeros separados con "-" queda la misma columna del inicio.

Cómo se debe aplicar correctamente la negación ^ o ?!  ? 
lo intente con `^[[0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2}]`, 
`^([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})`, 
`?![[0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2}]`, 
`?!([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})`

sin ningún resultado satisfactorio, cómo debería aplicar correctamente la negación?
Agradezco desde ya su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo una solución más simple a tu problema. mediante el paquete `stringr` tienes disponible `str_extract()` que te permitirá directamente "capturar" el patrón numérico que tienes

```
productos %>%
    mutate(producto = gsub('[/]','-',producto),
           X2 = gsub('([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})','',producto),
           X3 = str_extract(producto, '([0-9]+[-][0-9]+|\\d{2})')
    )
```

Nota: En expresiones regulares, la negación de un patrón individual puede hacerse por ejemplo así `[^0-9]` que hace coincidir cualquier caracter no numérico. Sin embargo la negación de patrones más complejos (mucho mas complicada de realizar) se hace mediante lo que se conoce como [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html?S_TACT=C34409NW)

Comment: Muchas gracias! resolvió el problema :) y gracias también por la aclaración de la negación en en casos más complejos